# how to set correct date format for user view in angularjs editable-date

Tags: angularjs, html, date

Basically I have an editable-date field in my angular app which is shown to user like:
    `mm/dd/yyyy` when the field is not selected

But I want to show to user as: `dd/mm/yyyy`. Where to set the format for display to user when field is not selected ?

Comment: By default browser will take the locale date format. That' you can't change unless you use a custom date picker. But if the user enters date format as mm/dd/yyyy while transferring to the backend you can change the date format

Comment: OK but I need it for serving an in house software and date formats are strictly in `dd/mm/yyyy` and my team is of the opinion that this dropdown could confuse sales people(the application is to be used by sales guys).

Answer (score 0):

Make a custom directive that require ngModel and changes the model view value. 
(this i would do in case i'm working with breeze entities for example, and i don't want to actually change the value or affect the entityState)

If that doesn't bother you, than use moment to format the date how you like.
(moment is a powerful js library with advanced format options)

Comment: I am not concerned about the value here, though I still have trouble integrating datefmt with Rails backend. But what I would want is before filling in the date user should see dd/mm/yyyy as a prompt. I tried bootstrap datepicker which has that feature but unfortunately it would not render the datepicker with form.